# Is it possible to manipulate the cookies of a remote computer via Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

**Some background information:**

I have already implemented a working Chrome extension to manipulate cookies from within the browser, not unlike [EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en). Basic functionalities include adding, removing, editing, importing and exporting cookies.

**Question:**

Currently, importing and exporting cookies work with JSON flat files that have to be sent around, so for increased convenience, I was wondering if it is possible to import the cookies on my local computer **directly into a remote computer** via my extension. Basically, I would like to 'push and set' cookies from one computer to another. For simplicity, both are signed into the same Google account. Of course there needs to be a way to identify and authenticate the remote computer so I'm thinking of possibly using any authentication APIs that might be available.

As this idea is still in its infancy, I would like to ask if this is even technically feasible? Are there any technical limitations regarding Chrome extensions (how they are sandboxed etc.) that I should know about that would prevent me from achieving this goal?

Comment: I think you'll need to be able to specify which hosts' cookies you want to edit. Even with wildcards, I don't believe you can actually give permission on all hosts i.e. "*".

Answer (score 2):

Assuming:

- Both Chrome instances are signed into the same account
- Extension is installed on both
- Chrome Sync is enabled for extensions (default)

In this case, [`chrome.storage.sync` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) automatically replicates changes to storage between the instances. All you need to do in that case is:

- Change cookies in one instance
- Record the desired cookie state in `chrome.storage.sync`
- Detect storage change in other instance with `chrome.storage.onChanged`
- Process the changes to replicate the cookie state

Be aware that `chrome.storage.sync` will not provide a transaction log of all changes - only the latest state. Trying to store the transaction log in `chrome.storage.sync` so that you can perform the exact same operations is likely to hit [storage quotas](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#property-sync) fast.

If the quotas or requirements of sync storage do not fit your use case, you'll need to make your own data backend server. It can communicate realtime updates to Chrome with [`chrome.gcm` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/gcm) or a WebSocket connection, and use Google's OAuth for authentication.

There also exist backend services that can be easier to use than rolling out own server, for example [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/). There's a [sample extension](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/auth/chromextension) to get started.

If you cannot assume that the other instance has the same extension installed, then you can't manipulate cookies remotely, as they are not synced by Chrome from remote sources.

Comment: What about when both Chrome instances are not signed into the same account as is the case for different users? Chrome sync would obviously not work then, so is the best solution to create my own user database backend?

Comment: Yes, I was just presenting a pure Extension API solution, but it requires Chrome Sync. Obviously, making your own backend is a hugely broad topic to fit here.

Comment: Added Firebase as an example solution for the backend.